# Search and Replace works from Command Line in Vim but not as Script

Tags: vim

I run the following myscript.vim file using `source: %` from the gVIM command line:

```
ls
arg *.vmrk
argdo %sno/Stimulus,S100/Response,R100/ge | update
argdo %sno/Stimulus,S101/Response,R101/ge | update
```

The input to `argdo` worked fine on its own, but the lines do not execute properly in the vim file. `ls` runs, indicating that the script is being called, but the files in the current directory remain unchanged, suggesting that argdo is not working or the lines are not being reached.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` works for the current file. However, it ignores the current path (gettable using :pwd). The solution was to change the path from the default (oops: C:\Windows\System32) to the current path by adding:

```
:cd %:p:h
```

before execution.